# How to correctly deallocate a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly deallocate or delete a c++ vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546239/how-to-correctly-deallocate-or-delete-a-c-vector)

I'm having some problems trying to delete memory that I've allocated in a vector. Even though I call list.clear(), it's not deallocating the memory.

So I have some code like this in a template-based class called Set

```
template <class T>
class Set {
public:
    // stuff
private:
    int size;
    std::vector<T> list;
};
```

And in the constructor, I have allocated memory for the vector. So I call list = new std::vector;

For your interest, here is my copy constructor and assignment operator that I've also witten where I also allocate memory for the vector:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(const Set& aSet)
{
    size = aSet.size;
    list->clear();
    list = new vector<T>;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        list[i] = aSet.list[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator=(const Set& right)
{
    if (this != &right) {
        list->clear();
        size = right.size;
        list = new vector<T>;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            list[i] = right.list[i];
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}
```

In the destructor, I just have list.clear() to delete all elements and then deallocate the memory.

But the problem is, when I run valgrind on my .out file, it's telling me that I've definitely lost some memory and I don't know why it's telling me this. I've read some questions here on Stackoverflow but I've basically tried everything. I tried clear() and then delete on the vector but that didn't work. I then tried to erase(list.begin(), list.end()) but that didn't work too.

My thought process is that I'm using a Set *aSet = new Set; in my main class and since an int is not an object, it's not being freed when I call list.clear(). Is this right? How would I go about deleting the memory correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Edit1 = changed list* to setList

My new constructors and the assignment operator:

```
template <class T>
Set<T>::Set(const Set& aSet)
{
    size = aSet.size;
    setList.clear();
    setList = aSet.setList;
}

template <class T>
Set<T>& Set<T>::operator=(const Set& right)
{
    if (this != &right) {
        setList.clear();
        size = right.size;
        setList = right.setList;
    }
    return (*this);
}
```

Valgrind still reports I have the same amount of lost memory though. In my destructor I still have list.clear()

Valgrind log:

```
==11398== 
==11398== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11398==     in use at exit: 62,969 bytes in 352 blocks
==11398==   total heap usage: 540 allocs, 188 frees, 68,046 bytes allocated
==11398== 
==11398== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11398==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks
==11398==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==11398==      possibly lost: 4,829 bytes in 56 blocks
==11398==    still reachable: 48,348 bytes in 277 blocks
==11398==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11398== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Comment: Kill the whole pointer and `new` business.

Comment: why not use vector by value? Also, are you trying to create a std::set on your own? Do you know about destructors?

Comment: Every `new` needs a matching `delete`. `clear()` removes all elements from the vector, and does not affect the memory of the vector object itself.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov I'm trying to create my own Set class that's templated since that's what my homework is.

Comment: @chris Since this is a template class Set, I want to be able to add objects to the set as well so I need new and the whole pointer business.

Comment: @watabou: No, you don't. You just need a vector.

Comment: @watabou, The code you've shown only uses the vector as a one-dimensional array, which doesn't require the use of pointers at all. You can change the size using things like `push_back` or `resize`.

Comment: @watabou: No you don't. You're already using `std::vector<>` so you should understand it implements a dynamically-sized array, which is exactly what your class seems to be implementing. In other words, you could just use a vector of vectors. "I'm using a Set *aSet = new Set; in my main class." Why? Just create it by value.

Comment: by the way, you have to define templates in the header

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov yep, that's what I'm doing. I only have a Set.h and a main.cpp file. I have my declaration and definition both in my Set.h file.

Comment: @GManNickG Okay, can you clarify what you mean by "create it by value"? Do I just do Set *aSet; and that's it? If I try to add item after doing this, I get a segmentation fault since it tells me my Set has not been initialized.

Comment: @watabou: Don't do this: `std::vector<T> *list;` do this `std::vector<T> list;` (notice the missing star). Then it creates the vector as a value and all memory management is correctly handled.

Comment: @LokiAstari Okay, I will do that now. I think I had some other errors regarding clang saying it couldn't find a viable '=' overloaded operator so I stuck a * in there so I thought that would fix all the errors. For future reference, when would I need to use a pointer to a vector?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to a vector when you need to dynamically create and delete vectors, instead of having one for the entire lifetime of your object. Although even then, you may want, say, a vector of vectors instead. You also might use a pointer to a vector for a case where you may or may not have a vector, but again there are often better solutions for those cases, such as `boost::optional`.

Comment: What is `setList`?  Where did that suddenly come from?  What happened to `list`?  It can't be the same thing renamed, because `std::vector` has no `addItem` member function.  Show your whole class, as it is now, including `"// stuff"`, and especially your destructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah no, a person here told me I shouldn't use list so I changed every list to setList. Sorry for the confusion. addItem is my method to add items to the Set.

Comment: What is the type of `setList`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Whoops, I see what you're saying. I changed addItem to push_back. Sorry, that was silly. I was concentrating too much on valgrind. Thanks. setList is a vector<T>

Comment: The for loop is unnecessary, you can just assign the vector all at once, i.e. `setList = aSet.setList;` -- Better would be to use the constructor initializer list, but one thing at a time.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I edited in my code now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My thought process is that I'm using a `Set *aSet = new Set;` in my main class and since an int is not an object, it's not being freed when I call list.clear(). Is this right? How would I go about deleting the memory correctly?

No. To delete the memory you allocate correctly you need to call delete:

```
Set *aSet = new Set;

delete aSet;
```

However manually managing memory like this is difficult and error prone. You should prefer alternatives. The first is that you should not use dynamic allocation at all. You should simply use automatic variables:

```
Set aSet;
// no delete required. Variable destroyed/deallocated when it goes out of scope.
```

If you really do need dynamic allocation you should use smart pointers.

```
std::unique_ptr<Set> aSet(new aSet);
```

Smart pointers implement RAII for dynamic allocation so you don't have to do it manually.

In some rare circumstances you may actually need to do dynamic allocation manually, but that's an advance topic.

---

`std::vector<T>::clear()` is not required to deallocate the vector's memory. You can use the C++11 member function `shrink_to_fit()`, or you can use the swap trick:

```
std::vector<int> list;

...

std::vector<int>(list).swap(list);
```

Also you really shouldn't be using a pointer to a vector. A vector uses RAII to manage dynamic memory for you. When you use a pointer to a vector you no longer have the benefit of not  manually managing the resource yourself.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I didn't know that. I think the reason why I was creating a pointer to a vector is because I got errors saying it couldn't find a overloaded '=' for list = new vector<T>. What should I do to fix this then? People are telling me I don't need the new here.

Comment: You don't need `new`. You just declare `list` to be a vector, `std::vector<T> list;` and then don't initialize it to anything in the constructor; It gets automatically initialized using vector's default constructor.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. That got rid of all the errors. I will report back after changing those things and then checking valgrind for any lost memory.

Comment: okay I removed all the pointers for Set and the vector. Now I just have Set<int> aSet; in my main class and that works but valgrind annoyingly still says I have lost memory. I am not using new anywhere in my code now.

Comment: IIRC valgrind should be reporting exactly where the lost allocations occur if you look at the detailed log info.

Comment: If I run valgrind with --leak-check=full, it reports back a bunch of nonsensical (to me) list. Stuff like: by 0x499F39: NXMapKeyCopyingInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==50605==    by 0x498D9D: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)

Comment: It's entirely possible that the leak is not actually in your code, but in some library you use.

Comment: So what's the proper way of deleting a vector again? Since I don't have a pointer to it anywhere and I'm not calling new anywhere in my code, I'm confused as to why valgrind is reporting the same exact lost memory before I removed all the pointers and new. In my destructor, I have vector<T>(list).swap(list); but that still doesn't work. clear() doesn't work either.

Comment: See above; the fact that valgrind is reporting a leak doesn't mean you're doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: @barnes53 Well I'm just worried because the assignment tells me that I need to manage memory and I'm afraid I will get docked points for any lost memory. Is that really fine that valgrind reports lost memory?

Comment: It's probably not 'fine' but if the mistake isn't in your code then you can't fix it.

Comment: @barnes53 All right I guess. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Before you do `new list` you need to do `delete list`, otherwise you'll get a memory leak as you've discovered. There's no need to `clear` the list before you delete it either, the destructor will automatically clear it. *Edit:* You also need to delete the pointer in the `Set` class destructor.

One little off-topic hint, don't use variable names like `list` that could be mistaken for built-in types.

A more on-topic hint is to use `std::vector` as a direct member variable instead of a pointer. In that case you would definitely need to use `clear`.

Comment: Why would he need to use `clear` in that case? When the `Set` is destroyed, its members will be destroyed, and `~vector` will get called and automatically clear it, just as if you'd called `delete` on a `vector*`.

Comment: I don't really understand this. If I delete my vector before using new, wouldn't that create an error? I just tried putting delete list and then list = new vector<T>; in my constructor but as I suspected, clang said "pointer being freed was not allocated".

Comment: @watabou, you need to make sure the pointer is set to `NULL` in your class constructor.

Comment: @abarnert, I assumed the reason for the `clear` was that old contents were being replaced with something new. I didn't read the code closely enough to verify that assumption. If the only time it's cleared is when it's destroyed, then it would indeed be redundant.

Comment: @watabou I think he's saying that in the assignment op you have to delete the old vector before creating the new vector. (At least I hope so.) Obviously in the constructors you have nothing to delete before calling new, and in the destructor you don't want to call new after delete, so the copy assignment operator is the only place it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in C++11 you can use [shrink_to_fit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). From what I understand though this is non-binding and implementation may prevent it from actually shrinking.

Comment: The reason that `shrink_to_fit()` is not binding is to allow for clever implementations. A decent implementation will only take advantage of that when there are actual benefits. For example the small string optimization allows dynamic allocation to be avoided entirely in some cases but would be prohibited if `shrink_to_fit()` were binding because the small string optimization implies a minimum capacity.

Comment: @bames53: `std::vector<>` isn't allowed to use small-buffer optimization.

Comment: @GManNickG That's correct, but vector isn't the only container with `shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: @bames53 in the case of vector, will the call always shrink capacity to size?

Comment: @NtscCobalt It's not guaranteed in the case of vector either.